# I made an asp.net mysql query. How can I get the surname data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

I made an asp.net mysql query. How can I get the surname data?

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE User_Name=@User_Name", conn); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Name", kullanici.ToString()); 
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
sonuclbl.Text = reader["surname"].ToString();
```

Comment: Please provide code as text. From your screenshot, you're clearly getting a compiler error. Please include the error message. At a guess, you've either declared `reader` somewhere above with the wrong type, or you've not declared it at all.

Comment: With that said, if you won't share your compiler errors with us, the image at least tells us that you have not declared the variable `reader`.

Comment: Please include your code as _text_. We cannot debug an image. Please include the error message as text.

Comment: Please see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for why we need text.

Comment: I updated the picture

Comment: @J... +1 for pointing out that an image of your code is not helpful.

Comment: MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE User_Name=@User_Name", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Name", kullanici.ToString());
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                sonuclbl.Text =  reader["surname"].ToString();

Comment: @Bilalİnal Please check the edited question. This is what commenters have pointed out. You can format your code easily, and doing so you help the readers of your question to comprehend better what is going on.

Comment: Please note that, in the future, it is much easier for everyone if you provide a complete [mcve].  If you go to a car mechanic and bring them just your steering wheel and tell them that the car doesn't turn correctly, they will tell you to come back with the whole car so that they can fix it.  Bringing just the steering wheel doesn't help them.  Same here.

Comment: By the way, connection, command and reader objects should be in `using` blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, you have to define the type of reader variable. It is not clear from the snippet you shared that you had done show.Then you have to loop through the reader, as it is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0):

```
var reader = cmd.Execute.Reader();
// Call Read before accessing data.
while (reader.Read())
{
    // Your code here to read from the reader
}
```

**Update**

From your updated post, it is clear that you need to define the type of variable called reader.

Answer (score -1):

```
var reader = cmd.Execute.Reader();

while (reader.Read())
{
 
 // your code example below
 string variableName = reader["ColumnName"].Tostring(); 
   
}
```

Comment: It seems like this is very alike the answer marked as a solution. Could you update it with further information if you feel like this contribute to the question?